# Memory-efficient MPI parallel implementation of element-wise sum of multiple arrays

Tags: c, mpi

I am quite new to MPI, and I would like to compute element-wise sum of two (or more) large arrays.
Naive implementation of this task will be like this (I apologize for any mistakes this pseudocode has. Please let me know if the standard implementation is substantially different):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#define NELEMS 10
#define NP 2
#define TAG 15

int setElements(int,int);

int postProcess(int *);

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int nprocs,myrank,*myarray,*result,i,initflag=0;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);
    myarray=malloc(sizeof(int)*NELEMS);
    if(myrank==0){
        result=malloc(sizeof(int)*NELEMS);
        if(myrank==0){
            result[i]=0;
        }
        initflag=1;
        for(i=1;i<NP;i++){
            MPI_Send(&initflag,1,MPI_INT,i,TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<NELEMS;i++){
        myarray[i]=setElements(myrank,i);
    }
    if(myrank!=0){
        MPI_Recv(&initflag,1,MPI_INT,0,TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }
    MPI_Reduce(myarray,result,NELEMS,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    free(myarray);
    /*At this point the element-wise sum should be stored on myrank==0*/
    if(myrank==0){
        postProcess(result);
    }
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

My concern is that this implementation requires `myrank==0` to allocate two arrays of size `NELEMS` (whereas one for `myrank!=0`), which might be problematic for large `NELEMS`. One trivial workaround (if available) is to use one more processor and make `myrank==0` idle until the `setElements` loop is completed in other processes, but this does not seem to be very efficient use of processors especially when the evaluation of `setElements` is computationally expensive.

So my question is: Are there any cleverer ways to calculate the element-wise sum of large arrays using MPI? Or should I consider a substantially different strategy?

Comment: OT: In `MPI_Isend`, you are missing the last argument, that is a pointer to `MPI_Request`. Why `MPI_Isend` and not simply `MPI_Send`? Also note that `free(result)` won't work for slaves where `result` is not initialized. Initialize it to `nullptr`, or `free` only for master.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica Oops. I originally posted my question using `MPI_Send`, but I later noticed this is inefficient if `setElements` is computationally heavy. So I changed to `MPI_Isend`, but I shouldn't have done that: probably the better way is to simply move the `MPI_Recv` block to just above the `setElements` loop.

Comment: As far as I saw, you really wrote C code. Hence, I removed the tag [tag:c++]. The community is a bit sensitive concerning tag spamming...

Comment: @Scheff I sincerely apologize: the tag was suggested by the system. I should have thought twice before actually inserting it. Thank you for the removal.

Comment: _the tag was suggested by the system_ Oh. I didn't know that there is such automatism. That explains why it appears periodically in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform the reduction *in place* on the root process. Quoting from the documentation:

> When the communicator is an intracommunicator, you can perform a reduce operation **in-place (the output buffer is used as the input buffer)**. Use the variable `MPI_IN_PLACE` as the value of the root process sendbuf. In this case, the input data is taken at the root from the receive buffer, where it will be replaced by the output data.

In your case, modify the `MPI_Reduce` call from:

```
MPI_Reduce(myarray,result,NELEMS,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

to:

```
if (my_rank == 0)
  MPI_Reduce(MPI_IN_PLACE,myarray,NELEMS,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
else
  MPI_Reduce(myarray,nullptr,NELEMS,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

With this approach, you don't need the second array (`result`) at all.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know `MPI_IN_PLACE`. I would love to accept your answer upon checking whether this works for me (+1 for now). Thank you very much!